# Magento 2.4.6 Localhost Install Windows 11

Tags: magento2, php, database, composer, apache

I am having issues installing Magento2 on my local machine. I have been following [this tutorial](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/magento-2-on-localhost/) but I run into the same issue where my localhost/magento2/pub/ page doesn't display content. I have been taking notes of things to watch out for when installing such as changing the Gd2.php script and verifying my .htaccess files. Here are my current install notes for my version and setup:

composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition=2.4.6-p3 magento2

php bin/magento setup:install --base-url="http://localhost/magento2/" --db-host="localhost" --db-name="magento2" --db-user="root" --admin-firstname="admin" --admin-lastname="admin" --admin-email="corbin.lamplot@kageinnovation.com" --admin-user="admin" --admin-password="admin123" --language="en_US" --currency="USD" --timezone="America/Chicago" --use-rewrites="1" --backend-frontname="admin" --search-engine=elasticsearch7 --elasticsearch-host="localhost" --elasticsearch-port=9200

I follow the commands after installation according to the tutorial I've been following. Here is a screen shot of the pub page with  my apache logs:
[image]
[image]

Here is my result when trying to access the admin page:
[image]
[image]

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Follow this tutorial link .. https://cloudkul.com/blog/learn-magento-2-4-installation-on-windows/

Comment: Thank you! This for sure helped.

Answer (score 0):

Please Set http://localhost/magento2/pub/ into your base URL this will work for you,

Because you have to add the base URL in http://localhost/magento2/ and index file into the pub directory that's why the content does not show.

so please change the base URL in store > configuration

Comment: Thank you! I did this with the recommendation from Keval and got it to work!